# chart.js in meteor not pulling data from context

Tags: meteor, charts, iron-router, chart.js

Answering myself: the issue (one of the issues) appears to have been that I was expecting an array of numerics where what I had in the collection was an array that included numerics... so the array needed to be parsed to isolate the data I was looking for. Once I got it to an array of numerics things got much easier.

here is the code to _pluck the correct field out of the array and then process that so it can be used:

```
    var lvl_min_raw  = _.compact(_.pluck(EDC_DATA.find({session_id: Session.get("current_session_id")},{fields: {lvl_min: 1}}).fetch(),'lvl_min'));
    var lvl_min_ints =  _.map(lvl_min_raw.map(Number), function(num){ return num - 256; });


    var lvl_max_raw  = _.compact(_.pluck(EDC_DATA.find({session_id: Session.get("current_session_id")},{fields: {lvl_max: 1}}).fetch(), 'lvl_max'));
    var lvl_max_ints = _.map(lvl_max_raw.map(Number), function(num){ return num - 256; });

    var lvl_avg_raw  = _.compact(_.pluck(EDC_DATA.find({session_id: Session.get("current_session_id")},{fields: {lvl_avg: 1}}).fetch(), 'lvl_avg'));
    var lvl_avg_ints = _.map(lvl_avg_raw.map(Number), function(num){ return num - 256; });

    var lvl_median_raw  = _.compact(_.pluck(EDC_DATA.find({session_id: Session.get("current_session_id")},{fields: {lvl_median: 1}}).fetch(), 'lvl_median'));
    var lvl_median_ints = _.map(lvl_median_raw.map(Number), function(num){ return num - 256; });

    var  label_array_length = lvl_median_ints.length; 
    var lvl_labels_raw = Array.apply(null, {length: label_array_length}).map(Number.call, Number)
    var lvl_labels_short = _.map(lvl_labels_raw.map(String), function(str){ return str; });
```

Working code is here: https://github.com/amstanley/ddt in case someone else runs into this. Hope it helps.

=================================================================

I am loading telemetry from a bunch of WiFi devices into a mongo database and want to display metrics from individual devices in real time so I can troubleshoot signal level and other issues. To do this I have set up a simple meteor application to access the data. I am now trying to use chart.js in meteor to provide the real time graphs.

The issue I am troubleshooting is that I can display a list data for any wifi session in real time, but I cannot seem to populate a graph with the same data. I am fairly certain this is a context issue, but after 8 hours or so of googling, I do not understand how to access the context properly to populate the data.

The actual error is:

> Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'new Chart(lvlCtx).line(data)')

The router looks like this:

```
   Router.configure({
      layoutTemplate: 'layout',
      loadingTemplate: 'loading',
      waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('Edc_Data'); },

    });

    Router.route('/', {
                name: 'activityList'
                });

    Router.route('/:session_id', {
                name: 'sessionPage',
                data: function() { return EDC_DATA.find({session_id: this.params.session_id},{sort: {_id: -1}}); }


    });
```

The template looks like this:

```
    <template name="sessionPage">

    <div class="navbar-header">
    Path: /session_id
  </div>

  WiFi Levels:
   <div> <canvas id="lvlChart" width="400" height="400"> </canvas> </div>

  Raw Data  
  <div>
  {{#each this}}  
     <p> {{household_id}} | {{time}} | {{session_id}} | {{lvl_min}} | {{lvl_max}} | {{lvl_avg}} | {{lvl_median}} | {{lvl_stddev}}</p>
  {{/each}}

  </div>
</template>
```

The chart function looks like this:

```
function drawChart(){        

        var data = {

          labels: this.time,

          datasets: [       

            {
                label: "lvl_min",
                data: this.lvl_min,
                color:"#F38630"
            },
            {
                label: "lvl_max",
                data:  this.lvl_max,
                color : "#E0E4CC"
            },
            {
                label: "lvl_avg",
                data:  this.lvl_avg,
                color : "#69D2E7"
            },          
            {
                label: "lvl_median",
                data: this.lvl_median,
                color : "green"
            },
            {
                label: "lvl_stddev",
                data: this.lvl_stddev,
                color : "red"
            }      
        ]
        };

          var lvlCtx = $("#lvlChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
          var lvlChart = new Chart(lvlCtx);
          new Chart(lvlCtx).line(data);

}
```

The autorun looks like this:

```
Template.sessionPage.rendered = function(){
    Deps.autorun(function () { drawChart();
                 });
};
```

When I load the page, the error "Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'new Chart(lvlCtx).line(data)')" will display in the error console. The template will render the items in the {{#each this}}...{{/each}} block on the page, below the canvas. From this I deduce that the context is being passed to the template, BUT NOT to the charts function, and as a result the data: fields are not populating, causing the error.

How do I access the context in the chart function so I can properly populate the data parameters? Any help is greatly appreciated.